# Using nmap to scan an entire range

Tags: nmap

I found many examples with nmap online, but I got curious and I could not find a more advanced command. For example, if I want to scan a rage of ip in this measure, 192.168.x.x, then from 192.160.0.0 to 192.168.255.255, what is the correct syntax? I cannot find it anywhere, I could only find with the last class, any idea? Thank you very much!

- To be more precise, just on a port, we could say -p 80 for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify multiple hosts by CIDR; for instance `192.168.0.0/16`.

The nmap man page shows several other ways to specify hosts, under the heading [`TARGET SPECIFICATION`](https://nmap.org/book/man-target-specification.html).